# Weblogic Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN

Tags: oracle, weblogic

I have a problem in Weblogic.
When you run the script startWebLogic.sh the weblogic does not start.
Below is the log.

oracle.security.jps.JpsRuntimeException: Cannot read from policy store.
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStore.buildFromFile(XmlPolicyStore.java:440)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStore.(XmlPolicyStore.java:227)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStoreProvider.getInstance(XmlPolicyStoreProvider.java:100)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStoreProvider.getInstance(XmlPolicyStoreProvider.java:74)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.runtime.ContextFactoryImpl.findServiceInstance(ContextFactoryImpl.java:139)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.runtime.ContextFactoryImpl.getContext(ContextFactoryImpl.java:170)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.runtime.ContextFactoryImpl.getContext(ContextFactoryImpl.java:191)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.runtime.JpsContextFactoryImpl.getContext(JpsContextFactoryImpl.java:132)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.runtime.JpsContextFactoryImpl.getContext(JpsContextFactoryImpl.java:127)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil$1.run(PolicyUtil.java:850)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil$1.run(PolicyUtil.java:844)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil.getDefaultPolicyStore(PolicyUtil.java:844)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyDelegationController.(PolicyDelegationController.java:291)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyDelegationController.(PolicyDelegationController.java:284)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.JavaPolicyProvider.(JavaPolicyProvider.java:270)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.loadOPSSPolicy(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1343)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1022)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
        at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: oracle.security.jps.JpsRuntimeException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntryStax(XmlDataStoreParser.java:166)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntry(XmlDataStoreParser.java:180)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntry(XmlDataStoreParser.java:187)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStore.loadXmlDataStore(XmlDataStore.java:418)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStore.(XmlDataStore.java:283)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStore.getInstance(XmlDataStore.java:216)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStore.buildFromFile(XmlPolicyStore.java:436)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered
        at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.prime(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:80)
        at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.setInput(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:99)
        at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(XMLStreamInputFactory.java:316)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntryStax(XmlDataStoreParser.java:98)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered
        at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.prime(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:69)
        ... 37 more
    
    (PolicyDelegationController.java:293)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyDelegationController.(PolicyDelegationController.java:284)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.JavaPolicyProvider.(JavaPolicyProvider.java:270)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: oracle.security.jps.JpsException: [PolicyUtil] Exception while getting default policy Provider
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil.getDefaultPolicyStore(PolicyUtil.java:899)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyDelegationController.(PolicyDelegationController.java:291)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyDelegationController.(PolicyDelegationController.java:284)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.JavaPolicyProvider.(JavaPolicyProvider.java:270)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: oracle.security.jps.JpsException: [PolicyUtil] Unable to obtain default JPS Context!
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil.getDefaultPolicyStore(PolicyUtil.java:844)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyDelegationController.(PolicyDelegationController.java:291)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyDelegationController.(PolicyDelegationController.java:284)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.JavaPolicyProvider.(JavaPolicyProvider.java:270)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: oracle.security.jps.JpsException: [PolicyUtil] Unable to obtain default JPS Context!
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil$1.run(PolicyUtil.java:860)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil$1.run(PolicyUtil.java:844)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyUtil.getDefaultPolicyStore(PolicyUtil.java:844)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.PolicyDelegationController.(PolicyDelegationController.java:291)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: oracle.security.jps.JpsRuntimeException: Cannot read from policy store.
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStore.buildFromFile(XmlPolicyStore.java:440)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStore.(XmlPolicyStore.java:227)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStoreProvider.getInstance(XmlPolicyStoreProvider.java:100)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.xml.XmlPolicyStoreProvider.getInstance(XmlPolicyStoreProvider.java:74)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.runtime.ContextFactoryImpl.findServiceInstance(ContextFactoryImpl.java:139)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: oracle.security.jps.JpsRuntimeException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntryStax(XmlDataStoreParser.java:166)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntry(XmlDataStoreParser.java:180)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntry(XmlDataStoreParser.java:187)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStore.loadXmlDataStore(XmlDataStore.java:418)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStore.(XmlDataStore.java:283)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered
        at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.prime(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:80)
        at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.setInput(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:99)
        at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(XMLStreamInputFactory.java:316)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntryStax(XmlDataStoreParser.java:98)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntry(XmlDataStoreParser.java:180)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Premature end of file encountered
        at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.prime(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:69)
        at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.setInput(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:99)
        at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(XMLStreamInputFactory.java:316)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntryStax(XmlDataStoreParser.java:98)
        at oracle.security.jps.internal.core.datastore.xml.XmlDataStoreParser.getDataStoreEntry(XmlDataStoreParser.java:180)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>

Comment: "Cannot read from policy store".

Answer (score 1):

You can check below RDBMS store setting:

a) Is the database is up or not which is storing RDBMS policy store username and password

b) Check if  some one change weblogic  password :
   If yes then you need to encrypt using weblogic tools encrypt utility and update same in config.xml at security realm tag and alos update in boot.properties

c) If nothing above works at last resort you can change the RDBMS policy store 
  authentication to plain username password which is default authentication mechanism.

Please let me know if it works or not